# How to set Vertical Alignment in Word add-ins javascript

Tags: javascript, office-addins, office-js, word-addins, office-2016

I have a problem about setting an alignment in paragraph 
in Word-js.
I want to set alignment at top or bottom of the page
for example

`var test = context.document.body.insertParagraph("test", "end");
test.alignment = "centered";
test.Verticalalignment = "top";`
Does it has a  method like Verticalalignment in word-js ?
Thank you